# Dterm for linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

Is there a something similar to DTerm available for Linux?

Comment: For clarification, this is the DTerm being referenced: http://www.decimus.net/dterm.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Guake](http://guake.org/) is the closest I can think of. It is a dropdown terminal like DTerm, but doesn't automatically change to the directory of the current document.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it helped. Also, if you didn't know already, after the time limit is up, click the checkmark next to my answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [dterm](http://www.knossos.net.nz/resources/free-software/dterm).

> dterm is a simple terminal emulator, which doesn't actually emulate any particular terminal. Mainly, it is designed for use with xterm and friends, which already do a perfectly good emulation, and therefore don't need any special help; dterm simply provides a means by which keystrokes are forwarded to the serial line, and data forwarded from the serial line appears on the terminal.
>
> dterm is invoked thusly:
>
> ```
> dterm [options|device ...]
> ```
>
> dterm attempts to read the file ~/.dtermrc for options; if this doesn't exist, it tries /etc/dtermrc. Then it parses the options passed on the command line.
>
> The options read should include a device name, e.g "ttyS0" or "ttyd0" for the first serial port on a Linux or FreeBSD system respectively. If no device is specified, dterm tries /dev/ttyS0, /dev/ttyd0, /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyU0.
>
> Once started, dterm can be got into command mode using Ctrl/]. Press enter once from command mode to get back into conversational mode. (The command character can be changed with the esc= option, e.g. esc=p to use Ctrl/P instead of Ctrl/].)

Comment: If there is a reason for the under-vote, please illuminate me.

Comment: `dterm` seems to be dead by now

Comment: @hoijui: The original article is still available from the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120520013737/http://www.knossos.net.nz/dterm.html) and the source can even be [downloaded](https://web.archive.org/web/20120318225936/http://www.knossos.net.nz/downloads/dterm-0.3.tgz). However, since this answer dates from 2010 and the last available version number was then 0.3, I wouldn't today recommend this product.